# PHP Preg_replace doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a number of files that has parts that need to be replaced. An example of such a file is:

```
    u101p-fr-2_2
    PAN,  'U101P-FR-2_2', P, BLO='U101P', DT=101, X=FR-2, AS4='M';
    CUR,  'CB1', COL=MAGENTA, LTY=SOLID, YZ, 6390.45,5985.01/
          0, 7341.23,6752.51/
          0, 7341.22,6752.5/
          R400.01, 7489.98,7063.74/
          0, 7489.98,8863.99;
    BOU,  'U101P-Y7800', SID=SB/ 'U101P-Z8800', SID=BOT/ 'CB1'/ Z=7063.74;
    PLA,  MAT=20, MSI=FOR, QUA=A, POS=179, NO=1, AS4='P';
    FLA,  PRO=10,200,20, CUR, LIM=3, QUA=A, POS=734, NO=1, COL=YELLOW, 
          CON=15, CUT=1100, EXC=30/ CON=45, CUT=1402,30;
    EXC,  TYP=TIP1, LIM=4, M1=30;
    NOT,  R50, COR=2;
```

For this particular example I have to replace **POS=179** to **POS=115** and **POS=734** to **POS=762**.

I can do it with Notepad++ using something like: **\bPOS\=179\b**
Also, it seems to work on different websites like http://regexr.com?33hti

However, in PHP, using preg_replace it does NOT WORK.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be nice if we could see your `preg_replace`

Comment: How are you calling `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Why not use `str_replace()` if it is a simple string replacement done and not pattern matching?

Comment: well, I have a whole table, and many files. I believe that if I have POS=2 and POS=21, per example it will alter the results.

Comment: If it's multiline as it looks, then you need the /m modifier with any regexp

Comment: still no luck, I have tried the /m modifier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe that if I have POS=2 and POS=21, per example it will alter
>   the results

You can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to avoid that:

Example:

```
$string = 'POS 2 POS 21 POS 27 POS 2 POS 21';

print strtr($string, array(
  'POS 27' => 'POS 420',          // find => replace
  'POS 2'  => 'POS 5',
  'POS 21' => 'POS 7',
));
```

The longest matches will be replaced first, so you won't run into any problems.

Comment: I have never thought at that... so, how should I put it? I have the old POS number and the new POS number in a MySQL Table...

Comment: Get the numbers, prepend `POS ` to them, and pass them as an array of keys (old numbers) and values (new numbers)

Comment: could you elaborate please? I'm not sure I've understanded :)

Answer (score 2):

So, you finally decided to divulge your code:

```
foreach (glob($path_SCH_ModelBun.$unitatea."/*.sch") as $filename){ 
  $file = file_get_contents($filename);
  echo "<pre>".$file."</pre><br /><br />";
  $search_for = "/\bPOS".preg_quote("=".$search_for)."\b/g";
  $replace_with= "POS=".$replace_with;
  echo $res = preg_replace($search_for, $replace_with ,$file);
  echo " <pre>".$file."</pre> ";
}
```

You are incorrectly using the `/g` flag. Enable [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) to learn why your regex fails. PHPs PCRE does not support that.

Also you are using `$res =` for assigning the modified file contents back.
But then you are writing out the unmodified original `$file` out again.

Comment: I am a new member and I have trouble formatting my code here :( sorry for that.

I have error_reporting(E_ALL); but I don't see any error / warning or even notices. I have removed the /g flag and the $res = , and still no luck

Comment: You are not supposed to remove the result variable. But write it out instead.

Comment: Could I do something to count out the modifications in each file? :-s

Comment: With `preg_match_all` first, replacing afterwards.

Comment: How about this exception: 

`STI,  PRO=10,100,10, SID=AFT, MSI=SB, QUA=A, NO=1(1)4, Y=8300,8900,9450,
      10050, POS=779(-1)776, COL=YELLOW, CON=45, CUT=1302,15, EXC=30/ 
      CON=45, CUT=1302,15;`   

Here, I have 4 POS Numbers in one statement, so the is 779, 778, 777 and 776.

In this case, either change both numbers (779 and 776) or change none and make some kind of note. Any ideas?

Comment: No. And it's a bit late to change the question scope with new weird conditions. No clue what you want.